# How to prevent ssh from interpreting remote command as a host?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, openssh, command-line-arguments

I set up a dedicated SSH key pair for the purpose of forcing a specific command on a remote server. I added the public key to the remote server authorized_keys file along with a command option specifying the command to be execute when this key is used. The command is a shell script which requires a single command line argument that I'm expecting to get passed in the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable.

When I execute the `ssh` command from the client and specify the use of this specific key like this:

```
ssh -i id_rsa_mykey -o User=abc -o HostName=myhost xxx
```

The remote script executes as expected and is passed the `xxx` in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable.

If I attempt to pass the remote command an email address however the remote `sshd` is interpreting the value as a `user@host` and appears to attempt authentication on the part before the `@` symbol and the remote command is never executed. `/var/log/auth.log` on the remote server has the error:

> ```
> Invalid user xxx from 192.168.0.1
> ```

How can I escape the `@` symbol or otherwise not have `sshd` evaluate the value as a `user@host` and instead pass the value as is to the remote command?

I've tried both attempting to backslash escape the `@` symbol as well as using `--` before the argument but `sshd` does not appear to support this end of arguments convention.

- Client machine is running Ubuntu with `ssh` version OpenSSH_7.2p2.
- Server machine is running Debian with `sshd` version OpenSSH_6.7p1

Comment: Did you try with `' xxx@yyy '`?

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work.  Good try though!  Remote sshd still reports same error.

Comment: I found a suitable workaround by passing the argument on stdin to the remote script but it still would still be nice to know if it is possible to pass the argument on the command-line.

Comment: I have no problem at all `ssh remothost ./Echo.sh xxx@yyy`.  Where Echo.sh is a script executable in the remote home. Please [edit] again your post and add the Systems on which you work, and the versions of `ssh` and `sshd`. BTW `-o HostName=myhost` myhost is the remote one. Try to put its IP address (`host myhost`). If still not enough try with `ssh -v ...` to have verbose output of the informations.

Comment: Note that if you are working in a script with variable and you write something like ` -o HostName=$myhost$command$address` and the first two variable are empty, ssh will think that the address is the username and host target of the connection. BTW I suppose you do not really need to use `-o HostName=myhost` you can directly write `ssh ... myhost  command option` even without `"` or `'` if there is nothing to be expanded or substituted by the shell...

Comment: This works if I modify the remote forced command to ignore the first argument and use the second argument.  An even better solution that works is passing the first argument as the empty string! i.e. `ssh -i key -o user=abc -o hostname=remotehost '' xxx@yyy`.  If you add this as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Why don't you do jsut `ssh -i id_rsa_mykey abc@myhost xxx`? Using the options for the `host` and `user` is very weird. And `ssh` does not interpret the second `@` on the command-line.

Comment: @Jakuje this works provided you are not using multiplexed connections.  Since i have this configured in my ssh config file I had to add `-o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none` to the command line in order to leave out the user and hostname options.  Not sure if this is a bug or by design.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your reasons to use `-o User=abc -o HostName=myhost` over `abc@myhost`.

> … however the remote `sshd` is interpreting the value as a `user@host` and appears to …

No, I think it's your local `ssh` that interprets this.

In my Debian the first argument that cannot be interpreted as an option is interpreted by `ssh` as `host` or `user@host`, depending on whether `@` is there or not. After this no other argument is interpreted in such way, even if there's `@` in it.

Now some observations:

- `user` from `user@host` takes precedence over `-o User=abc`,
- but `host` (standalone or from `user@host`) is suppressed by `-o HostName=myhost`.

Conclusion: while using `-o HostName=myhost`, `host` doesn't matter. This makes the following possible:

```
ssh -i id_rsa_mykey -o User=abc -o HostName=myhost dummy_host foo@bar
```

Thanks to the presence of `dummy_host`, `foo@bar` is passed to the remote side as a command, even though it includes `@` character. Still `ssh` connects to `myhost`, not `dummy_host`, because `-o HostName=myhost` takes precedence.

Note: `dummy_host` may or may not be `myhost`. It may even be blank (`""`).