# Securing $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND on a SSH proxy server

Tags: linux, ssh, security, proxy

I want to setup a SSH server that acts as a proxy between the client and the "real" SSH server. I do this by utilizing `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config`. `ForceCommand` points at a script that does some extra stuff before forwarding the session, using something similar to the following line:

```
ssh $theRealSSHServer $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

`$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is there because I need to do command execution over SSH. To protect my proxy server from malicious users I plan to do the following before forwarding the session:

```
if echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" | grep "[^a-z|A-Z|0-9|[:space:]|_|-]" ; then
    echo "Illegal command: $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    exit 1
fi
```

I.e. I only allow a limited set of characters, which should make it impossible to insert any commands that will be executed locally on the proxy server (like `; rm -rf /`). This impose a fairly big limitation on commands possible for execution but is better than a static approach with a dictionary. I really don't want to use a dictionary with trusted commands, which seems to be the recommended way of solving this, http://at.magma-soft.at/sw/blog/posts/The_Only_Way_For_SSH_Forced_Commands/.

Is my way "safe"? If not, can it be fixed or is this approach unacceptable from a security perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ssh $theRealSSHServer $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
> ```

This command, although somewhat flawed, doesn't allow command injection easily.

Even if unquoted, a variable containing`; rm -rf whatever` will not execute `rm`. Control operators like `;` are identified before variable expansion occurs. When the variable gets expanded, the logic of the command line is already fixed, additional `;` cannot alter it; it's just a literal `;`. The same applies to a snippet like `$(rm …)` popping out upon variable expansion.

Still an unquoted variable undergoes variable expansion (obviously), word splitting and filename generation. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618). You can easily interfere with what an honest user wants to do on the target server. Examples:

- The user invokes `ssh proxy 'echo "I  need  double  spaces"'`. They get single spaces in the response.
- The user invokes `ssh proxy 'echo some/location/*'`. `*` is expanded *on the proxy* and the result is passed to the target server to be arguments to `echo` there. The user will not see what they want.
- Not only they will not see what they want; they may trigger unwanted action on the target server. Imagine the expansion will get them `some/location/; rm -rf whatever` (a legitimate name). This will be *interpreted* on the target server. There `whatever` will be removed (if permitted). Note `rm` can take multiple operands; so if there are more matches on the proxy that appear after `some/location/; rm -rf whatever`, their counterparts on the target server will be removed (if permitted).

A malicious user can take advantage. Examples:

- The user invokes `ssh proxy 'echo /etc/*'`. It's almost like executing `ls /etc/` on the proxy. How about `/boot/`, `/lib/modules/` and subdirectories? Obtained information may help them prepare an attack.
- The user may pass options to `ssh` your script invokes. E.g. if they type `ssh proxy -- '-o HostName=another_server -o User=impostor -p 22'` then they will initiate a connection to another server, regardless of `$theRealSSHServer` in your script (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1320991/432690)). There are more options they can (ab)use. Double-quoting `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` will make most such tries fail. The real countermeasure is [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618).

The command in your script should be

```
ssh -- "$theRealSSHServer" "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

Now you don't need to sanitize the original command, unless you want to do this for the target server maybe. Locally (on the proxy) this is safe.

---

Other parts of the script may still use the variable in a way that allows execution of (some part of) it. It's your job to make sure they don't. Examples:

- The variable provides the first word of a command.

  - (obvious)

    ```
    SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND="echo foo"
    $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

    SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND="date"
    "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    ```
  - (less obvious)

    ```
    SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND="date"
    cmmnd=""
    $cmmnd "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    ```

    Note that strict double-quoting of all variables would prevent this one.
- The expanded content gets interpreted on the proxy. (It is meant to be interpreted, but only on the target server).

  - (obvious)

    ```
    SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='date; echo foo'
    eval "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    ```
  - (less obvious)

    ```
    SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND="foo'; date'"
    sh -c "printf '%s\n' '$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND'"
    ```

    Compare [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). The safe way is `sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1"' sh "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"`.

If your script doesn't do such things then double-quoted `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` will not inject code on the proxy server.

---

Note users may specify options like `-L`, `-t` or `-o` in their `ssh` invocation. Options will not affect the connection to the target server. At least cover `-t`/`-T`, request tty or not, depending on whether the user got tty on the proxy or not:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then t=-t; else t=-T; fi
ssh "$t" -- "$theRealSSHServer" "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

If your script was only to forward connections (not doing "extra stuff"), then it would be better to request users to use `ProxyJump` instead.

If your goal is to suppress some commands on the target server then you should probably apply some restrictions there, not on the proxy (set proper permissions, use some kind of restricted shell, …).